# Add ASG instances in target group via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a Terraform script which creates a launch config, autoscaling group, a single ALB, one target group and a listener. The instances are launched using the autoscaling group.

How can I add the newly launched instances in target group via Terraform in the same script?

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "CF2TF-LC" {
  name                 = "CF2TF-LC"
  depends_on           = ["aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.CF2TF-IAM-PA", "aws_security_group.CF2TF-SG-Web"]
  image_id             = "ami-14c5486b"
  instance_type        = "t2.micro"
  iam_instance_profile = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.CF2TF-IAM-IP.id}"
  key_name             = "CF2TF"
  security_groups      = ["${aws_security_group.CF2TF-SG-Web.id}"]
  user_data            = "${template_file.CF2TF-UserData.rendered}"
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "CF2TF-ASG" {
  name                      = "CF2TF-ASG"
  depends_on                = ["aws_launch_configuration.CF2TF-LC"]
  vpc_zone_identifier       = ["${aws_subnet.CF2TF-Subnet-1a.id}", "${aws_subnet.CF2TF-Subnet-1d.id}"]
  max_size                  = 3
  min_size                  = 2
  health_check_grace_period = 300
  health_check_type         = "EC2"
  desired_capacity          = 2
  force_delete              = true
  launch_configuration      = "${aws_launch_configuration.CF2TF-LC.id}"
}

resource "aws_lb" "CF2TF-ALB" {
  name               = "CF2TF-ALB"
  subnets            = ["${aws_subnet.CF2TF-Subnet-1a.id}", "${aws_subnet.CF2TF-Subnet-1d.id}"]
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = ["${aws_security_group.CF2TF-SG-Web.id}"]

  tags {
    Name        = "WebSrv"
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "CF2TF-TargetGroup" {
  name        = "CF2TF-TargetGroup"
  depends_on  = ["aws_vpc.CF2TF-VPC"]
  port        = 80
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = "${aws_vpc.CF2TF-VPC.id}"
  target_type = "instance"

  health_check {
    interval            = 30
    path                = "/index.html"
    port                = 80
    healthy_threshold   = 5
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
    timeout             = 5
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    matcher             = "200,202"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "CF2TF-ALB-Listener" {
  //depends_on = ["aws_lb.CF2TF-ALB.id", "aws_lb_target_group.CF2TF-TargetGroup.id"]
  load_balancer_arn = "${aws_lb.CF2TF-ALB.arn}"
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.CF2TF-TargetGroup.arn}"
    type             = "forward"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The `aws_autoscaling_group` resource takes a [`target_group_arns` parameter](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#target_group_arns) that will register the ASG with the target group so that all instances are registered with the load balancer's target group as they come up and properly drained from the load balancer before being terminated.

As such your ASG resource should look something like this:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "CF2TF-ASG" {
  name                      = "CF2TF-ASG"
  depends_on                = ["aws_launch_configuration.CF2TF-LC"]
  vpc_zone_identifier       = ["${aws_subnet.CF2TF-Subnet-1a.id}", "${aws_subnet.CF2TF-Subnet-1d.id}"]
  max_size                  = 3
  min_size                  = 2
  health_check_grace_period = 300
  health_check_type         = "EC2"
  desired_capacity          = 2
  force_delete              = true
  launch_configuration      = "${aws_launch_configuration.CF2TF-LC.id}"
  target_group_arns         = ["${aws_lb_target_group.CF2TF-TargetGroup.arn}"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The aws_autoscaling_group resource implements a parameter, [target_group_arns](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#target_group_arns) to do exactly what you need. Just add this line to your autoscaling group resource:

```
target_group_arns = "${aws_lb_target_group.CF2TF-TargetGroup.arn}"
```

Comment: :) Great! Remember to mark the answer as correct if it fulfils the requirements

Comment: Done...Thanks again